# Editing code to order listbox items in descending numeric order

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2013, listbox

I'm trying to generate a Report for the project which shows which counties (Cork,Carlow, etc.) are most popular. Currently I have been able to find each iteration of a customers county and display it in a list box(lstReports) like this...

```
Antrim= 0
Armagh= 1
Carlow= 2
Cavan=  1
```

and so on so forth

I wanted to make it so on the click of a button I could sort the list in numeric acceding order(btnNumericAc) and descending order(btnNumericdec)...

eg. Accending

```
Antrim= 0
Armagh= 1
Cavan= 1
Carlow= 2
```

e.g. Decending

```
Carlow= 2
Armagh= 1
Cavan= 1
Antrim= 0
```

I was able to find a piece of code that orders my project by ascending, I was wondering what edits I would have to make to the code to order by decending. There was no explanation about how the code worked, so I am unsure what edits to make.

The code:

Class Code:

```
Public Class CountiesSorter 
Implements IComparer(Of String)

Public Function Compare(ByVal x As String, ByVal y As String) As Integer Implements System.Collections.Generic.IComparer(Of String).Compare
    Dim xai As Integer = x.IndexOf(" ")
    Dim yai As Integer = y.IndexOf(" ")
    Select Case True
        Case xai = -1 AndAlso yai = -1
            Return x.CompareTo(y)
        Case xai = -1 AndAlso yai > -1
            Return -1
        Case xai > -1 AndAlso yai = -1
            Return +1
        Case xai > -1 AndAlso yai > -1
            Dim xs As String() = x.Split(" ")
            Dim ys As String() = y.Split(" ")
            Select Case xs(1).CompareTo(ys(1))
                Case 0 : Return xs(0).CompareTo(ys(0))
                Case -1 : Return -1
                Case +1 : Return +1
            End Select
    End Select
End Function
End Class
```

Function Code:

```
Public Sub SortAccendingListBox(ByRef lb As ListBox)
    Dim il As New List(Of String)
    For Each i As String In lb.Items
        il.Add(i)
    Next
    il.Sort(New CountiesSorter)
    lb.Items.Clear()
    lb.Items.AddRange(il.ToArray)
End Sub
```

Button Code:

```
Private Sub btnNumericAs_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnNumericAs.Click
SortAccendingListBox(lstReports)
End Sub
```

Thank you for your help and time.

Comment: Techinally, you need to tell your Sorter class to sort descending, perhaps in the constructor, then just flip the return value for Desc.  But you would be much better off using a simple class to store the Name and Value so you could sort by an actual value rather than numerals because "19" > "100".

Comment: Why you make things that hard? Create a `County` class containing `Name` and `Popularity`.  Create a `List<County>` and fill it with counties. Then sort it using `OrderBy(x=>x.Popularity)` or `OrderByDescending(x=>x.Popularity)`. Then set the sort result as `DataSource` of your `ListBox` and set `DisplayName` of `ListBox` to `Name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `County` class containing `Name` and `Popularity`.
Then Create a `List<Conuty>` and fill it with counties.
Then sort it using `OrderBy(x=>x.Popularity)` or `OrderByDescending(x=>x.Popularity)`. Then set the sort result as `DataSource` of your `ListBox`.

**Code**

Here is the code for `County` class:

```
Public Class County
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Popularity As Integer
    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return String.Format("{0}= {1}", Me.Name, Me.Popularity)
    End Function
End Class
```

Here is the code for `Form`:

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim Counties As New List(Of County)
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Counties = New List(Of County) From
        {
            New County() With {.Name = "Antrim", .Popularity = 0},
            New County() With {.Name = "Armagh", .Popularity = 1},
            New County() With {.Name = "Carlow", .Popularity = 2},
            New County() With {.Name = "Cavan", .Popularity = 1}
        }
        Me.ListBox1.DataSource = Counties.OrderBy(Function(x) x.Popularity).ToList()
    End Sub
    Private Sub SortAscending_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SortAscending.Click
        Me.ListBox1.DataSource = Counties.OrderBy(Function(x) x.Popularity).ToList()
    End Sub

    Private Sub SortDescending_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SortDescending.Click
        Me.ListBox1.DataSource = Counties.OrderByDescending(Function(x) x.Popularity).ToList()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Thank you works great, this is a much cleaner way of doing it.